How to run ps1 files on intune?
I need to add a powershell script that changes a data value in registry editor. The script is running well on my local computer but not sure how to convert it to intune package properly. I can't use intune remediations because i have no permissions to use it. Is it possible to use this script as win32 app ?
I've created two powershell script and used Win32 Content Prep Tool to convert them to a intune package then uploaded the .intunewin file to intune as win32 app and filled the required blanks correctly and configured detection rules as well but whenever I try to install it on company portal it fails.
Tried to run those scripts from a cmd file as well but didn't work.
I used registry detection method.

Hello Oğuz,
Deploying a PowerShell script is not that difficult. To identify what the issue is, Try the below steps first.

Execute the script manually from a client PC and ensure that the expected change is reflecting on registry
Detection rule plays a crucial role on deploying a package through Intune. Instead of keeping the detection rule as a registry value, Try with a plain file name - C:\Temp\ScriptChceck.txt or something similar. The objective is to make sure that detection rule fails to detect the file and trigger the deployment.
Review the configuration on the deployment. Since its a script, I would suggest to run it under system context
If its failing, Validate the Intune logs from client side
